# ORA-03137: malformed TTC packet from client rejected

Tags: c#, oracle, bulk-operations

In C# I am doing bulkcopy in oracle database then another stored procedure is called with oracle managed data access.
Bulk copy is successful and inserts records in table. Next, when stored procedure executed getting the following error :

> ORA-03137: malformed TTC packet from client rejected:
> [kpoal8Check-3] [16384] [0] [0x000000000] [265512] [] [] []
> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
> PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
> "CORE 12.2.0.1.0 Production"
> TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
> NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production

Tried to set the environment variable CC_ORA_DISABLE_BATCH_ERRORS=TRUE; but of no use.
What is the fix for this error?

Comment: Do you have an Oracle Support account? This is quite possibly a bug; if so it may require a patch.

Comment: thanks. i have oracle account. can i use the same

Comment: They're different things. Oracle Support is something we have to pay for. If you're working for an organisation which licenses Oracle database it's worth asking the question.

Comment: thanks. i work as consultant. can you help me to find out the patch for this.